# Facebook Graph retorna um id diferente do que é salva usando passport-facebook

Tags: node.js

Tenho uma aplicação onde o usuário efetua o login usando a conta do facebook, salvando o id, nome e email. Estou usando https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook 
Segue trecho:

```
//Cria um usuario do facebook ou vincula a um usuario ja existente
UserSchema.statics.findOrCreateFaceBookUser = function(profile, done) {
    var User = this;
    User.findOne({
        'email': profile.emails[0].value
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (user) {
            user.facebook = {
                id: profile.id,
                email: profile.emails[0].value,
                name: profile.displayName
            };
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                } else {
                   // done(null, user);
                }
            });
            done(null, user);
        } else {
            User.findOne({
                'facebook.id': profile.id
            }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                //if (err) return done(err);
                if (user) {
                    done(null, user);
                } else {
                    User.create({
                        firstName:profile.name.givenName,
                        lastName:profile.name.familyName,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        gender:profile.gender,
                        image:"http://graph.facebook.com/"+profile.id+"/picture?type=normal",
                        facebook: {
                            id: profile.id,
                            email: profile.emails[0].value,
                            name: profile.displayName
                        }
                    }, function(err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        done(null, user);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    });


};
```

O problema é que preciso buscar os amigos do facebook que também estão usando a aplicação, mas o id retornado pelo facebook graph não bate com o que estou persistindo na aplicação.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name&access_token=xpto

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Nickolas, esta sua aplicação foi criada antes ou depois da introdução da API 2.0?
Lembre-se que agora o ID retornado é o *app-scoped ID* e não mais o *Facebook ID*.
Se for o caso, faça o *upgrade* de sua aplicação ou chame o `/me/friends`usando a `v1.0` ou `v2.0` conforme o caso.

Dê uma olhada em https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids